# Как прочитать файл через FileInputStream?

Tags: java, android, файлы

Имеется архив в res/raw

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется код:

```
private static File getFileFromPath(Object obj, String fileName) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = obj.getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
    return new File(resource.getPath());
}

private ZipInputStream getMagicFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            getFileFromPath(this, "res/raw/magic_info.zip")));
}
```

Но никак не получается его прочитать, летит вот такой набор ексепшенов:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.anonym.Project1.ExampleUnitTest.getFileFromPath(ExampleUnitTest.java:21)
at com.example.anonym.Project1.ExampleUnitTest.getMagicFile(ExampleUnitTest.java:26)
at com.example.anonym.Project1.ExampleUnitTest.testModule(ExampleUnitTest.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так, только надо контекст передать

```
 private ZipInputStream getMagicFile(Context ctx) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new ZipInputStream(ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.magic_info.zip));
}
```

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо! Но только без расширения файла (.zip).